# How to change private variable from global scope? Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, scope

Is it possible to change `localVar` local variable of below function from global scope

```
function test(){
    var localVar = 'I am a local variable !';
    console.log(localVar)
}
```

**UPDATE**
If it is a oop , I can do some thing like this ,but i dont need this

```
test.prototype.localVar = 'Changed ' ;
```

Comment: Then what *do* you need? The question you're asking doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Lest you doubt me, Douglas Crockford (one of the developers of the JavaScript language) confirms that a `var` declared in a function is "private".

http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html

Answer (score 0):

That would sort of defeat the purpose of scoping :)

If you create an object out of `test` and attach the localVar to the instance, then you can modify that, e.g.

```
function test(){
    this.localVar = 'I am a local variable !';
}

var obj = new test();
obj.localVar = 'newval';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want object oriented, why not just pass in a function argument?

for example:

```
    function test(localVar){
       var localVar = localVar || 'I am a local variable !';
       console.log(localVar)
    }
```

This way, when no argument is supplied it will return: 'I am a local variable !'. When you do specify a argument it will return what you put in there.